# Why nzBeforeUpload with option multiple is called multiple times

Tags: ng-zorro-antd

I'm using Angular 10 and ng-zorro and I am using nz-upload component, and I have a question:

Why beforeUpload is called equal to files uploaded? if we have a nzFileUpload[] parameter, its like a repetition not wanted

My .html code:

```html
 <div>
   <nz-upload
      ngDefaultControl
      nzType="drag"
      (click)="form.get('files').markAsTouched()"
      [nzDirectory]="false"
      [nzBeforeUpload]="beforeUpload"
      [nzDisabled]="false"
      [nzLimit]="fileMaxQuantity"
      [nzSize]="0"
      [nzListType]="'text'"
      [nzMultiple]="true"
      [nzShowUploadList]="false"
      [nzShowButton]="false"
      (nzChange)="handleChange($event)"
       >
       <p class="ant-upload-drag-icon" style="margin-bottom: unset;">
          <i nz-icon nzType="cloud-upload"></i>
        </p>
        <p class="ant-upload-text">{{ '::FileUpload:FilesUploadMessage' | abpLocalization }}
        </p>
        <p class="ant-upload-hint">
           {{ '::FileUpload:FilesUploadHint' | abpLocalization }}
        </p>
    </nz-upload>
    <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('files').hasError('required') && form.get('files').touched">
       {{ '::FileUpload:FilesFieldRequired' | abpLocalization}}
     </mat-error>
    </div>
```

And my .ts (beforeupload):

```js
beforeUpload = (singleFile: File, fileList: File[]): boolean => {
    // if (this.form.controls.files as FormArray)
    const fileNames = this.form.controls.fileNames.value as [];
    if (fileNames.length === this.fileMaxQuantity) {
      this.snackBarService.warning(this.localizationService.instant('::FileUpload:NumberFilesExceedsAllowed'), true);
      return false;
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i <= fileList.length; i++) {
        const file = fileList[i];
      // _.each(fileList, (file) => {
        if (this.form.controls.fileNames.value.length === this.fileMaxQuantity) {
          this.snackBarService.warning(this.localizationService.instant('::FileUpload:NumberFilesExceedsAllowed'));
          break;
          // return false;
        } else {
          const tempStackSize = this.actualFileStackSize + file.size;
          if (file.size > this.fileMaxSize || tempStackSize > this.fileMaxSize) {
            this.snackBarService.warning(this.localizationService.instant('::FileUpload:FileTooHeavy'), true);
            return false;
          } else if ( !this.fileList.some( p => p.name === file.name ) ) {
            const ext = this.extensionPipe.transform(file.name);
            let control: FormControl;
            (this.form.controls.files as FormArray).push(new FormControl(file.name));
            (!this.regexWithExt.test(file.name)) ?
              this.fileListRequired.push(true) : // debe cambiar filename
              this.fileListRequired.push(false);

            control = new FormControl(file.name.replace(ext, ''),
              [ Validators.pattern(this.regex),
                Validators.required,
                Validators.maxLength(this.fileNameMaxLength - ext.length),
                this.fileNameValidator()]);
            control.markAllAsTouched();
            (this.form.controls.fileNames as FormArray).push(control);
            // fileNames.push(file.name);
            this.fileList.push(file);
            this.actualFileStackSize = tempStackSize;
          }
        }
      }
      // fileList.forEach((file) => {
      // });
    }
    return false;
  }
```

From the above, the problem is that this function `beforeUpload` is called equal to list size of files.

Comment: Please show some code to look into your problem. It would be nice to see your `<nz-upload ...` element and your `beforeUpload ` function.

Comment: @xDrago I updated the description, thanks!

Comment: If you see the console log, write "up" for each file that is uploaded:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wszv2f?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I tested it and it seems to work as they want it to. The method is called for each file seperately. It is the same in my projects aswell.

Comment: Principal issue is that the Toast appear's multiple times if the validation not pass. You believe that i could open a issue in github to cancel subscription at error?

Comment: Ah I see. As a workaround you can create a local variable `error` or something like that which you set to true on any error and check that variable after the last file got processed. And sure you could open an issue for that.

Comment: I will use the workaround that you mentioned while, Thank you! =)

Comment: No problem :) Glad I could help.